# iOS phone showing different back button than simulator

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, back-button, navigationbar

I have not set the button using any image, its just the default back button that is generated when embedded in a nav controller.

In the simulator it has the normal back button icon < 
But on the phone it displays more of a iOS 6 back button.

The target is set to iOS 10+

What could be the issue?

Here is what it looks like on my device (which is wrong):
[image]

As far as I'm aware, back buttons don't look like this any more

Comment: This is Accessibility setting on the phone, go into settings and check the General > Accessibility > Button Shapes function.

Comment: That did the trick thanks. No idea why this randomly changed though